# Why is this code not performing the calculation correctly? Volume of a sphere given a radius

Tags: arrays, c, math, volume, calculation

Title says is all. The math is wrong for calculating the volume given a radius, but the calculation for the area is correct.

```
#define _CRT_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS
#define _USE_MATH_DEFINES

#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <math.h>

float radius[4][3];
int x = 0;
int main()
{
    while (x < 4)
    {
        printf("Please enter Radius %d: ",(x+1));
        scanf("%f", &radius[x][0]);
        radius[x][1] = ((4 / 3) * M_PI * pow(radius[x][0], 3));
        radius[x][2] = M_PI * pow(radius[x][0], 2);
        x++;
    }
    x = 0;
    while (x < 4)
    {
        printf("\n\rThe volume for a sphere with the radius %.2f is %.2f", radius[x][0], radius[x][1]);
        printf("\n\rThe area for a circle with the radius %.2f is %.2f", radius[x][0], radius[x][2]);
        x++;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: `(4 / 3)` is treated as integer math and yields the value `1`. To get a floating point result, one or both of the operands should be a floating point constant, e.g. `(4.0 / 3)` or `(4.0 / 3.0)`.

Comment: Allergic to for loops?

Answer (score 2):

`4 / 3` has integers for both operands, so integer division is performed.  This truncates the result toward 0, giving a result of 1.

Use floating point constants to perform floating point division.

```
radius[x][1] = ((4.0 / 3.0) * M_PI * pow(radius[x][0], 3));
```

Comment: regarding:  `(4.0 / 3.0)`  these are `double` literals, not floating point.  Suggest: `(4.0f / 3.0f)`

Comment: @user3629249 I said they were floating point, not `float`.  Besides, better to use `double` for better precision in most cases, particularly since all most operands in the full expression have type `double`.

Answer (score 2):

In this line: `radius[x][1] = ((4 / 3) * M_PI * pow(radius[x][0], 3));`

This operator `(4 / 3)` is an integer division, because both left and right operands are integers {`4` and `3`) so it will truncate to 0.

`4 / 3 = 1.33333333333333333...` but the result is truncated, so it will return `1`.

Use floating point:

`radius[x][1] = ((4.0f / 3.0f) * M_PI * pow(radius[x][0], 3));`

Or typecast it into `float` type.

`radius[x][1] = (((float)4 / 3) * M_PI * pow(radius[x][0], 3));`

Comment: regarding:  `(4.0 / 3.0)`  these are `double` literals, not floating point.  Suggest: `(4.0f / 3.0f)`

Comment: @user3629249 Aside: C specifies `4.0`, `3.0` as _floating constants_.  C specs 2 _literals_: _string_ and _compound_.  They are of type `double`.

Answer (score 2):

In addition to going from integer division where `(4 / 3)` is `1` to floating point division, consider using consistent math types:

```
double radius[4][3];
radius[x][1] = ((4.0 / 3.0) * M_PI * pow(radius[x][0], 3));
radius[x][2] = M_PI * pow(radius[x][0], 2);
```

or

```
#define M_PIf 3.1415926535897932f
float radius[4][3];
radius[x][1] = ((4.0f / 3.0f) * M_PIf * powf(radius[x][0], 3));
radius[x][2] = M_PIf * powf(radius[x][0], 2);
```

---

I'd stay with `double` and take advantage of prior multiplications rather than call expensive `pow()`.

```
double radius[4][3];
radius[x][2] = M_PI * radius[x][0] * radius[x][0];        // pi * r^2
radius[x][1] = (4.0 / 3.0) * radius[x][0] * radius[x][2]; // 4/3 * r * area
```